# TCP connection refused when using ffserver / ffmpeg

Tags: tcp, ffmpeg, ffserver

I am getting a "TCP connection to localhost:8090 failed: Connection refused" error when trying to use ffserver on Ubuntu 10.04LTS Desktop.

I am typing:

> ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 30000/1001 -i /dev/video0 -f avi -vcodec mjpeg -r 30000/1001 `http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm`

Here is the full output:

```
Input #0, video4linux2, from '/dev/video0':  
Duration: N/A, start: 1314207657.841770, bitrate: N/A  
   Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [SAR 96:96 DAR 16:9], -5 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc  
[tcp @ 0x9e58980] TCP connection to localhost:8090 failed: Connection refused  
[buffer @ 0x9e58260] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:yuvj420p tb:1/1000000 sar:96/96 sws_param:  
Output #0, avi, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm':  
  Metadata:  
    ISFT            : Lavf53.8.0  
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [SAR 96:96 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc  
Stream mapping:  
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0`
```

ffserver seems to acknowledge the request though:

```
Wed Aug 24 13:40:57 2011 127.0.0.1 - - [POST] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 1356
```

Where is the problem? How can I use ffmpeg correctly?

Comment: What command line are you using to launch ffserver?

Comment: What happened to this problem? Were you able to solve it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/560511/ffmpeg-connection-refused

Answer (score 12):

I was having the same issue, here's what worked for me:

in the /etc/ffserver.conf file put:

```
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
```

then in the <feed></feed> section add:

```
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
```

assuming your network ip is 192.168.x.x

then start your server:

```
ffserver -d -f /etc/ffserver.conf
```

Comment: `BindAddress` option is deprecated. Use `HTTPBindAddress` instead

Comment: this was 7 years ago, i'm surprised any of this is still valid

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are not allowed connect or possibly that the service is not there.

You sure you have

1. Started ffserver and that it is on 8090?
2. That you have set

   ```
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
   ```

or

```
     ACL allow localhost
```

in you ffserver configuration file in the   clause?